# Error: Unable to initialize main class Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/conversions/Bson

Tags: java, mongodb, jar, executable-jar, bson

https://github.com/Gjonathan252/AutoPart-Java-Database-w-MongoDB

Its my first time using maven and I am trying to run the .jar of my program but I keep getting this error in the command prompt when I run.

```
java -jar autopartsjavamongodb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

result:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.example.autopartsjavamongodb.main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/conversions/Bson
```

The Java program uses mongodb dependencies and they all seem to be working when I run the program on the IDE or using this long command on the command prompt.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=63226:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\Computer Science Lessons\AutoPart Java Database w MongoDB\target\classes;C:\Users\gjona\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\mongodb-driver-sync\4.3.1\mongodb-driver-sync-4.3.1.jar;C:\Users\gjona\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\bson\4.3.1\bson-4.3.1.jar;C:\Users\gjona\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\mongodb-driver-core\4.3.1\mongodb-driver-core-4.3.1.jar" com.example.autopartsjavamongodb.main
```

This is what the pom.xml file looks like. I dont think I am missing any depencacies as I am able to run it on the IDE.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>autopartsjavamongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.example.autopartsjavamongodb.main</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when we package a project into a jar file, the jar file doesn't contain its dependencies, so the dependency jar files would need to be included in the classpath.
One way to achieve that is by using [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)

As a result, all the dependency jars would be packaged in one jar.

pom.xml example

```
            `<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.example.autopartsjavamongodb.main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>`
```

Also please note **pluginManagement** tag is used to define the plugin version in your parent POM, in your case you shouldn't include pluginManagement tag